# Trying to send two values from php to JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Im retrieving a value from my db, displays on screen as a **0.**

```
echo "<article>" . $gr_display['status'] . "</article>";
```

Then when im clicking on this DIV i want to send both status and id to my JS function, edit. The ID of this object is **79**

```
echo "<div onclick='edit( " . $gr_display['status'] . "." . $gr_display['id'] . " )' </div>";
```

Then the start of my script

```
function edit(status, id) { 
console.log(status, id ); some code later }
```

But im ending up with the result that id and status is combined into one sett of value, leaving the other one "undefined"

From console log: **0.79 undefined**

Comment: You put a "." instead of a comma. ` $gr_display['status'] . "**,**" . $gr_display['id']`

Comment: **carefull** if ur Status string contains ` \ ` u probably break ur page

Comment: You also forgot to add the `>` for the opening `<div>`. Adding it in my answer. `:)`

Comment: Thanks for the help mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace div with this:-

```
echo "<div onclick='edit( " . $gr_display['status'] . "," . $gr_display['id'] . " )' </div>";
```

Comment: Why should the OP "use this code"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help mate

Answer (score 4):

Please make a clarity between PHP and JavaScript. You need to use the right separator and separate.

```
echo "<div onclick='edit( " . $gr_display['status'] . ", " . $gr_display['id'] . " )'> </div>";
//-----------------------------------------------------^
```

Replace `.` with `,`. Also please use `>` for the opening `<div>`. You forgot to close your opening `div`.

Answer (score 3):

you have at typo change the `.` into`,` between the 2 variables

```
    echo "<div onclick='edit( " . $gr_display['status'] . "," . $gr_display['id'] . " )'> </div>";
//---------------------------------------------------------^
```

or better use data-attributes

```
echo "<div class='edit-element' data-status='" . $gr_display['status'] . "' data-id='" . $gr_display['id'] . "'></div>";

    $('.edit-element').click(function(){
          console.log($(this).attr('data-status'),$(this).attr('data-id'));
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is causes by this line:

`echo "<div onclick='edit( " . $gr_display['status'] . "." . $gr_display['id'] . " )' </div>";`

Notice that between the two arguments you put a '.' instead of a ',' (a comma). That way, the second argument in your JS function does not have a value

Comment: Thanks for the help mate

Answer (score 1):

> Your code has two issues
>
> 1. You haven't close opening div tag
> 2. Use , to separate two parameters

```
echo "<div onclick='edit( " . $gr_display['status'] . ", " . $gr_display['id'] . ")'>ddd </div>";


<script type="text/javascript">
    function edit(status, id) { 
        alert(status);
        alert(id);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help mate